# The overflow menu icon in Toolbar

Tags: java, android

I m using the **appCompat v7:24.2.1** and I just took a simple Tutorial about materials. I just cant figure out how to get the **Overflaw menu** in the **right-side** of the **toolbar** that created.

[The tutorial that i used..](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pMO8EVkhJO8)

### Custom app_bar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#F44336"
>
```

### main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.ud.materialdesigntest.MainActivity">

<!-- Was inside the RelativeLayout Tag
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
-->


<include
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    layout="@layout/app_bar" />

<TextView
    android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World"
    android:id="@+id/textViewHelloWorld" />
```

### main.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below code :

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.my_icon);
```

To change the overflow icon you can define a style like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverFlow</item>
</style>

<style name="OverFlow" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/my_overflow_menu</item>
</style>
```

In any case, it could be not a good idea to change a standard icon, like the overflow menu.

If you would like to change the color of the icon you can use:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  app:theme="@style/ThemeToolbar" />


<style name="ThemeToolbar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

   <!-- navigation icon color -->
   <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/my_color</item>

    <!-- color of the menu overflow icon -->
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/my_color</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I saw that post. But i just want it get appeared in the toolbar instead of putting a customized thing in there.

Comment: Okay, you will try to implement the custom toolbar.